# multiple Groupby on result of GroupBy Linq

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I've Two classes let's say

```
class Foo
{
 List<Bar> Bars{get;set;} 
}

class Bar
{
  string Name{get;set;}
  string Value{get;set;}
}
```

and i have a query like this

```
var resultsGroupedByState=Foos.GroupBy(x=>x.Bars.First(c=>c.Name=="state").Value);
```

that will return results grouped by states , moreover user can define a hierarchy of group by Fields for example

1. groupBy State
2. groupBy County
3. groupBy City and so on

How many levels of groupBy I've to do ,i don't know upfront. I've to do a groupby defined first in hierarchy , then do a groupby based on second value in hierarchy on results of first groupby and it continues on.

at the end i've to generate an xml from that data like this.

```
<State value="anyState">
   <County value="anyCounty">
       <City value="anyCity">
          ..........
        </City>
    </County>
 </State>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to generate XML. One solution can be to recursively do `GroupBy` and create `XMLDocument` directly.

Here is a helper class that can do that.

```
public class XmlGenerator
{
    private XmlDocument _document;
    private List<string> _fields;
    private int index = 0;

    public XmlGenerator(List<string> fields)
    {
        _fields = fields;
    }

    public void GenerateXML(IEnumerable<Foo> lookupData, XmlElement root, string field)
    {
        var fieldGrouping = lookupData.GroupBy(v => v.Bars.First(x => x.Name == field).Value);
        foreach (var grouping in fieldGrouping)
        {
            var element = _document.CreateElement(field);
            var attrib = _document.CreateAttribute("value");
            attrib.InnerText = grouping.Key;

            element.Attributes.Append(attrib);
            root.AppendChild(element);

            // If that is last field. No need to do any grouping.
            if (index < _fields.Count - 1)
            {
                // After each nested call update the nested level.
                // If GenerateXML do another that will be upon next nested level
                index += 1;
                GenerateXML(grouping, element, _fields[index]);
                index -= 1;
                // Make sure to change back nested level index otherwise that will not works if you have multiple groups.
            }
        }
    }

    public string GenerateXML(IEnumerable<Foo> lookupData)
    {
        _document = new XmlDocument();
        var root = _document.CreateElement("Root");
        _document.AppendChild(root);
        index = 0;

        GenerateXML(lookupData, root, _fields[index]);

        return _document.OuterXml;
    }
}
```

What actually I've done here is, I've stored all list of fields inside `List<string>.` And wrote a helper method that groups by a specific field. Each time pass I pass that method data that need to be grouped by and name of field by which you want to group by.

Hope so, that solves your problem.

Comment: thanks that points to the solution i've been looking for but i was stuck first making that hierarchy then iterating through that to generate xml, anyways it solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need GrroupBy.  Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           string xml =
               "<Root>" +
                    "<State value=\"AState\">" +
                       "<County value=\"ACounty\">" +
                           "<City value=\"ACity\"/>" +
                           "<City value=\"BCity\"/>" +
                           "<City value=\"CCity\"/>" +
                        "</County>" +
                       "<County value=\"BCounty\">" +
                           "<City value=\"ACity\"/>" +
                           "<City value=\"BCity\"/>" +
                           "<City value=\"CCity\"/>" +
                        "</County>" +
                       "<County value=\"CCounty\">" +
                           "<City value=\"ACity\"/>" +
                           "<City value=\"BCity\"/>" +
                           "<City value=\"CCity\"/>" +
                        "</County>" +
                     "</State>" +
                    "<State value=\"BState\">" +
                       "<County value=\"ACounty\">" +
                           "<City value=\"ACity\"/>" +
                           "<City value=\"BCity\"/>" +
                           "<City value=\"CCity\"/>" +
                        "</County>" +
                       "<County value=\"BCounty\">" +
                           "<City value=\"ACity\"/>" +
                           "<City value=\"BCity\"/>" +
                           "<City value=\"CCity\"/>" +
                        "</County>" +
                       "<County value=\"CCounty\">" +
                           "<City value=\"ACity\"/>" +
                           "<City value=\"BCity\"/>" +
                           "<City value=\"CCity\"/>" +
                        "</County>" +
                     "</State>" +
                     "<State value=\"CState\">" +
                       "<County value=\"ACounty\">" +
                           "<City value=\"ACity\"/>" +
                           "<City value=\"BCity\"/>" +
                           "<City value=\"CCity\"/>" +
                        "</County>" +
                       "<County value=\"BCounty\">" +
                           "<City value=\"ACity\"/>" +
                           "<City value=\"BCity\"/>" +
                           "<City value=\"CCity\"/>" +
                        "</County>" +
                       "<County value=\"CCounty\">" +
                           "<City value=\"ACity\"/>" +
                           "<City value=\"BCity\"/>" +
                           "<City value=\"CCity\"/>" +
                        "</County>" +
                     "</State>" +
                    "</Root>";

           XElement root = XElement.Parse(xml);

           List<Foo> foos = Helper(root); 

        }
        public static List<Foo> Helper(XElement element)
        {
            if (element.HasElements)
            {
                string tagName = ((XElement)element.FirstNode).Name.LocalName;

                List<Foo> children = element.Elements(tagName).Select(x => new Foo()
                {
                    Name = tagName,
                    Value = (string)x.Attribute("value"),
                    foos = Helper(x)
                }).ToList();


                return children;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    public class Foo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public List<Foo> foos { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: While this code fragment may answer the OP's question, the answer would be more useful if you'd add an explanation. Note that code-only answers tend to be flagged for quality review, which may cause them to be deleted.

Comment: This code goes from xml to list of Foos. I think the question wanted the opposite: from a list of Foos to xml.

Comment: yeah @vyrp is right, your solution is a reverse of what i wanted.Anyways thanks for effort